# How to understand this Unity Coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CoroutineExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Start ()
    {
        print ("Starting " + Time.time);
        yield return StartCoroutine (WaitAndPrint ());
        print ("Done " + Time.time);
    }

    IEnumerator WaitAndPrint ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (5f);
        print ("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
    }
}
```

The result is

```
Starting 0
WaitAndPrint 5.010554
Done 5.010554
```

I have two questions?

First, How to understand the return value of function Start(). I used to see the return value of Start() is void. And in my view, Start() only executes once (one frame) by Unity, but yield return seems make Start() function execute in two frames;

Second, I am also confused by the result. I think the result should be

```
Starting 0
Done 5.010554
WaitAndPrint 5.010554
```

Because StartCoroutine() starts the function WaitAndPrint(). In function WaitAndPrint(), *yield return* makes this function pause in this frame and return to Start(). Then Start() continues going on and prints "Done xxxxx". After 5 seconds, WaitAndPrint() resume and
prints "WaitAndPrint xxxxx".

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `yield return` the control is taken by Unity.

When you start a `Coroutine` Unity will take the `IEnumerator` returned by the method and will call [MoveNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `IEnumerator` returned.

Based on the type of object and on the values in the object Unity will decide what to do.

In you case in the `Start` method the `yield` statement return another `IEnumerator` so Unity will not call `MoveNext` on the `Start` returned object until the second `IEnumerator` finishes.

In `WaitAndPrint` the first `MoveNext` returns a `WaitForSeconds` object, based on that Unity decides that it will **not** call `MoveNext` on in until 5 seconds have passed. After 5 seconds it calls `MoveNext` again and the rest of the method is executed, which is just this line

```
print ("WaitAndPrint" + Time.time);
```

As the `IEnumerator` returned by `yield return StartCoroutine (WaitAndPrint ());` reached its end it will call `MoveNext` on the `IEnumerator` that was returned by `Start`, this in turn will execute what ever is left of `Start`:

```
print ("Done " + Time.time);
```

Hope this is clear enough :)

Comment: Based on the type of object and on the values in the object Unity will decide what to do.
That is the point!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I understand this result :

The Start() function is called once by Unity and prints "Started".

Then the following line does two things :

```
yield return StartCoroutine (WaitAndPrint ());
```

- it starts the WaitAndPrint() coroutine
- it waits for it to be over before continuing in the Start() coroutine.

The WaitAndPrint() coroutine will do its stuff :

- Wait for 5 seconds
- Print "WaitAndPrint" + time

Then the Start() coroutine will resume and print "Done" + time.

This is why

```
print ("WaitAndPrint" + Time.time);
```

is printed before :

```
print ("Done " + Time.time);
```

Also, you should edit your post, it misses a space in the first result :

```
WaitAndPrint5.010554
```

Should be

```
WaitAndPrint 5.010554
```

Sorry if it's not clear, it's my first time answering on StackOverflow, hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerators` are iterator blocks, they dont necessarily execute for 1 frame, when you put a `yield return`, you essentially are telling it to iterate over multiple frames.

> When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method,
>   expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IEnumerators you can "nearly" always use Invoke method. Try to work with that one and your life will be easier :)